# Кодировка XML файла и записываемых данных

Tags: xml, utf-8, кодировка

Создан XML файл. В него записываются данные с сайта, по умолчанию в кодировке UTF. На выходе требуется получить данные в файле XML в кодировке w-1251.

Предполагал, что если добавлю атрибут `encoding` со значением `Windows-1251`, то кодировка текста соответственно будет `Windows-1251`. Но текст остался в `UTF`

---

Атрибут `encoding` не должен по умолчанию конвертировать текст файл в заданную кодировку?

Comment: Некоторые xml-парсеры умеют извлекать кодировку именно из атрибута `encoding`, но большинство не умеют. Поэтому не стоит на это полагаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Атрибут `encoding` не должен по умолчанию конвертировать текст файл в
>   заданную кодировку?

Атрибут `encoding` только указывает название кодировки. Поэтому, если Вы хотите чтобы файл был в нужной кодировке, Вам нужно его соответствующим образом преобразовать.

Comment: т.е. атрибут предназначен только для чтения. Мне не понятна его ценность, т.е. если при чтении XML нет необходимости в этом атрибуте, то можно его не указывать совсем?

Comment: Этот атрибут и не является обязательным. Однако лучше его всё-таки указывать, т.к. это может упростить жизнь при работе с данным XML за счёт того, что сразу понятно в какой он кодировке.